# Best way to connect 3/4" copper pipe to 1/2"

Tags: plumbing

My main copper water lines are 3/4" but in a new bathroom undoubtedly the valves are 1/2" so it will need to be stepped down.

What is the highest quality way to do this?

I presume the basic approach is that a copper fitting with a 3/4" in and 1/2" out is soldered onto the pipe.

Comment: Reducing fittings in the form of tee's, ell's and couplings are very common.  Your basic approach assumption is correct - is there something more specific you were worried about?

Comment: Look for fittings tagged 3/4x1/2